# integrate openfeint to cocos2d ipad layout

Tags: ipad, layout, cocos2d-iphone, openfeint

I integrated successfully openfeint to my app on iPhone/iPod Touch. But the layout is broken on the iPad.
I copy pasted the code from the sample app from openfeint.

```
- (void) performOpenfeintInitLogic
{
    UIViewController * rootVC = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
    NSDictionary* settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait], OpenFeintSettingDashboardOrientation,
                              @"asdasdasdas", OpenFeintSettingShortDisplayName,
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], OpenFeintSettingEnablePushNotifications,
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], OpenFeintSettingDisableUserGeneratedContent,
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], OpenFeintSettingAlwaysAskForApprovalInDebug,
#ifdef DEBUG
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:OFDevelopmentMode_DEVELOPMENT], OpenFeintSettingDevelopmentMode,
#else
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:OFDevelopmentMode_RELEASE], OpenFeintSettingDevelopmentMode,
#endif
                              window, OpenFeintSettingPresentationWindow,
#ifdef DEBUG
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:OFDevelopmentMode_DEVELOPMENT], OpenFeintSettingDevelopmentMode,
#else
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:OFDevelopmentMode_RELEASE], OpenFeintSettingDevelopmentMode,
#endif
                              nil
                              ];    
    [OpenFeint initializeWithProductKey:@"hgghf"
                              andSecret:@"nbvnb"
                         andDisplayName:@"ncvnv"
                            andSettings:settings
                           andDelegates:nil];

    [OpenFeint launchDashboard];

    OFGameFeedView * gameFeed = [OFGameFeedView gameFeedView];
    [rootVC.view addSubview:gameFeed];
}
```

Here the broken layout
[image: iPad broken layout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its running now with this configuration. The error was a wrong bundle. This is the right one: OFResources_Universal.bundle.

The config is now:

```
UIViewController * rootVC = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.window.rootViewController;
    NSDictionary* settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight], OpenFeintSettingDashboardOrientation,
                              @"asdasdads", OpenFeintSettingShortDisplayName,
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], OpenFeintSettingGameCenterEnabled,
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], OpenFeintSettingEnablePushNotifications,
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], OpenFeintSettingDisableUserGeneratedContent,
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], OpenFeintSettingAlwaysAskForApprovalInDebug,
#ifdef DEBUG
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:OFDevelopmentMode_DEVELOPMENT], OpenFeintSettingDevelopmentMode,
#else
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:OFDevelopmentMode_RELEASE], OpenFeintSettingDevelopmentMode,
#endif
                              rootVC, OpenFeintSettingPresentationWindow,
#ifdef DEBUG
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:OFDevelopmentMode_DEVELOPMENT], OpenFeintSettingDevelopmentMode,
#else
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:OFDevelopmentMode_RELEASE], OpenFeintSettingDevelopmentMode,
#endif
                              nil
                              ];    
    [OpenFeint initializeWithProductKey:@"asdasdas"
                              andSecret:@"asdasdasd"
                         andDisplayName:@"asdasdsad"
                            andSettings:settings
                           andDelegates:nil];
```